# Swift drag UIImage in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know it is possible to directly drag `UIImage` in Swift code, which looks like this

[image]

But somehow I am unable to get it working.

I tried to drag the *image@3x.png* from resources to code but the dragged image points to some other image, need to know how to get these image literals working.

Comment: just type the name of the image in code, it will autocomplete

Comment: Ok, I click on the right image literal, then it shows me file options. I click image.png or image@3x.png, but no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to use like this you should add image to your project directory bt dragging in Xcode or by adding it in assets folder. otherwise when you create build this image will be missing.

Comment: Note that image literals seem to be some kind of deprecated feature seeing how their support is regressing with newer versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

you must have the image in your Assets.xcassets folder. Then after typing Image Literal autocomplete double click the icon and select your image from the collection. If you have too many images, and you still want to use the Image literals, then comment the ImageLiteral line, and write the exact name into the init of #imageLiteral, like this :
`// #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NameOfYOurPicture")`
then uncomment it, and you will have your image there